# Error chroot "/bin/bash: error while loading shared libraries: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: file too short"

Tags: shared-libraries, live-cd

I need to install a kernel because I deleted them by mistake. So I booted from a live CD, I opened and mounted my LUKS and LVM volumes:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdf5 my_encrypted_volume
sudo mount /dev/mapper/my_encrypted_volume /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

And when I do

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

I get

```
/bin/bash: error while loading shared libraries: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: file too short
```

And

```
ls -l /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2; file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
```

says

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 ene 28  2013 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 -> libdl-2.15.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: symbolic link to `libdl-2.15.so'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/24266/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-file-too-short

Comment: Please run `ls -l /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2; file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2` and copy-paste the output into your question.

Comment: Did you boot from the elementary OS live CD, or some other live CD? Oh, and I should have mentioned: did you run these commands in the chroot or on the live CD? Because the interesting information is about the one in the chroot. Please confirm that this is in the chroot, or if it isn't, please run `ls -l /mnt/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2; file /mnt/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2` And there's a third one I forgot: `ls -lL /mnt/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2`

Comment: Could you check the size of the file : libdl-2.15.so Can you give us the result of the following command : sudo apt-cache policy libc6 Regards, Nicolas